# Split string after last number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I split the below to ignore the number?

```
1 Somewhere Street = Somewhere Street

10/45 Your Street = Your Street

76/1 Your Valley Road = Your Valley Road
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If numerical always at start position then you can use `substring()` with `patindex()` :

```
select substring(col, patindex('%[a-z]%', col), len(col))
```